# OpenSSH Requires Password AND Public Key

Tags: centos, ssh, openssh

I've inherited an old CentOS-6 system with OpenSSH 5.3 installed. And OpenSSH is behaving oddly: Currently the daemon requires the use of a public key **and** a password in order to login. (It's been this way for as long as I can recall.) And now I need to be able to login with only a password *or* a key - But **not** both!

I've verified that these settings are configured on the daemon:

```
[root@cp ~]# grep -v '#' /etc/ssh/sshd_config | grep -v ^$
Protocol 2
SyslogFacility AUTHPRIV
PermitRootLogin yes
RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
PermitEmptyPasswords no
PasswordAuthentication yes
ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes
GSSAPIAuthentication no
GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes
UsePAM yes
AcceptEnv LANG LC_CTYPE LC_NUMERIC LC_TIME LC_COLLATE LC_MONETARY LC_MESSAGES
AcceptEnv LC_PAPER LC_NAME LC_ADDRESS LC_TELEPHONE LC_MEASUREMENT
AcceptEnv LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_ALL LANGUAGE
AcceptEnv XMODIFIERS
X11Forwarding yes
UseDNS no
Subsystem   sftp    /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server
AllowUsers eric@*
AllowUsers techsup@*
   <<<snip>>>
```

I've checked /var/log/secure. And found these two lines *after a successful login*:

```
Feb  6 22:33:21 cp sshd[28717]: Accepted keyboard-interactive/pam for root from X.X.X.X port 25075 ssh2
Feb  6 22:33:21 cp sshd[28717]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
```

I've tried debugging the login process. And *this stood out*:

```
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /home/eric/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:Z2LEkZcy7/ntslBfeMFMh0WoOdt9xneuXX9VMSYv4VU agent
debug1: send_pubkey_test: no mutual signature algorithm
debug1: Offering public key: /home/eric/.ssh/id_ed25519 ED25519 SHA256:SjsJwvjUB3dVgurbsHTPooUOsGchvHGaYHy3VRS7who agent
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Offering public key: /home/eric/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:pDRJBoQKu0Ast8ypN15C6moeZ6I7lOawnj3IIgkFNjM agent
debug1: send_pubkey_test: no mutual signature algorithm
```

How can I disable this behavior so that I can login with either a password *or* a key?

TIA,

Eric Pretorious

Reno, Nevada

Comment: "Currently the daemon requires the use of a public key and a password in order to login" – Try `ssh -i /dev/null …`, give the password when prompted, see if you can log in, verify your statement and report back.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Yes - I'm able to login by providing my password when using /dev/null as my key.

Comment: So the server does not exactly "require password AND public key", the password is enough. I think your keys do not work. Investigate `no mutual signature algorithm`.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I'm using ssh-agent locally. When I login from a system where I'm NOT using ssh-agent: I'm NOT able to login using the password!

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski i.e., When I login from a remote system where I'm NOT using ssh-agent: I don't receive a password prompt!

Comment: Have you added the key with `ssh-add-key`? Have you looked at `ssh -v ...`?

Comment: OpenSSH 5.3 (on the server) supports for RSA keys only obsolete `ssh-rsa` algorithm which client 8.8 up disables (and doesn't support ed25519 at all). See https://superuser.com/questions/1748022 https://superuser.com/questions/1778874 https://serverfault.com/questions/1092998 https://serverfault.com/questions/1110112 (@KamilMaciorowski)

Comment: UPDATE: I've confirmed that a key is required before the client even receives a prompt for their password! (Reminder: I need to be able to login with _either_ a key *or* a password but *not* both.)